# How to identify XML nodes that represent an Array when parsed to JSON

Tags: ruby, json

For the purposes of parsing XML into a JSON string, I want to identify which nodesets in the XML markup would equate to the "[" (i.e. are arrays) in JSON format.

The best way I figure to identify such nodes are to find the ones that close then immediately re-open like the "Firms" node below:

```
 <Firms>
  <Firm>
   <Location />
   <ServiceType />
  </Firm>
  <Firm>
   <Location />
   <ServiceType />
  <Firm>
 <Firms>
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 with Nokogiri.

Does anyone know a good way that I can do this? ( or a better way perhaps?)

Comment: Not clear Dear.. Need to be more specific. Where is `[` things in your data ?

Comment: Do you have a DTD for this XML, that should tell you which element types are arrays.

Barring that, if your convention is plural contains singular, you could use the rails helpers pluralize and singularize to see if a child node is the same name as a parent node. Of course, then you are at the mercy of those helpers agreeing with you.

Comment: Thanks. There is a schema document, the live one is by the sec at this link http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/BulkFeed/CompilationDownloadLinks.aspx It shows complex types, but I can't really see how to identify  arrays from them, as they could be different node names.  I think String/scan might be the answer though. I can maybe use good old regex, just trotting off to have a go

Comment: Arup  hi and thanks for the response, I'm planning on dropping in the "[" into the JSON where there is an array, I'm pretty close to getting a nice why to convert the xml into the json except for the opening and closing nodes that map to an array in the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the DTD and see if the element has the attribute maxOccurs set to "unbounded". Load these in as arrays.